# Docker dm_task_run failed error

Tags: docker

Today I first time installed docker on Fedora 21. Now, I need change location of docker images folder from default /var/lib/docker.

After copying files (devicemapper subfolder skipped, docker service stopped) and changing /etc/sysconfig/docker (adding -g option), I run docker service again, no problems, devicemapper/metadata created.

Next, I'm trying to pull first image:

```
docker pull centos
```

But this error occured:

```
docker pull centos
latest: Pulling from docker.io/centos

6941bfcbbfca: Download complete 
6941bfcbbfca: Error downloading dependent layers 
41459f052977: Downloading [==========================>                        ] 41.61 MB/77.28 MB
fd44297e2ddb: Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/centos, endpoint: https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/, Driver devicemapper failed to create image rootfs 6941bfcbbfca7f4f48becd38f2639157042bfd44297e2ddb: Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/centos, Driver devicemapper failed to create image rootfs 6941bfcbbfca7f4f48becd38f2639157042b5cf9ab8c080f1d8b6d047380ecfc: Error running DeviceCreate (createSnapDevice) dm_task_run failed 
FATA[0013] Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/centos, Driver devicemapper failed to create image rootfs 6941bfcbbfca7f4f48becd38f2639157042b5cf9ab8c080f1d8b6d047380ecfc: Error running DeviceCreate (createSnapDevice) dm_task_run failed
```

If I try this without changing location - ok, no problems.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As seen in [issue 3721](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3721), this generally is a disk space issue.

The problem is that [`docker rmi` doesn't always work in that case](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3721#issuecomment-63344780):

> Getting this in v1.2 on CentOS 6.5 if a disk fills up before the image finishes pulling. Unable to rmi the incomplete image.

One ["nuclear" option](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=179942):

> removing everything in `/var/lib/docker` worked out. Thanks

Another reason can be a  [common layer of fs to be downloaded between two images](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9718#issuecomment-68762458).

Comment: I ran out of disk space on / (centos 7.2) and the only thing I could do to recover was removing /var/lib/docker and starting over.  Thanks.

Comment: I got a question. if I chose nuclear option all of containers will be lost, right?

Comment: @JuneyoungOh yes, even running ones.

Answer (score 59):

1) `service docker stop`

2) `thin_check /home/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata`

3) `thin_check --clear-needs-check-flag  /home/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata`

4) `service docker start`

Comment: Thank you, this worked great for me on centos. The issue started when a partition got full.

Comment: worked also great for me on centos 7. same issue as @gyaani_guy

Comment: This has worked for me, except on SUSE, the path is /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata .

Comment: Worked for me too - on redhat7!

Comment: This worked for me also, but on my openSUSE, the path was /home/docker/docker-data/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata

Comment: Worked without any problem! Thanks!

Comment: wow! worked like a charm @ Amazon Linux.
Linux xxxxxxx 4.9.27-14.31.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed May 10 01:58:40 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Thank you. it worked for me as well. The path is "/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata" on CentOS

Comment: Doesn't work as `thin_check` - where shall I get it from (centos)?

Comment: Same issue as @gyaani_guy, this worked well!

Comment: Works for me using `/data/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata`. But why does it work? What does `thin_check` do and what was the original problem?

Answer (score 4):

This was worked for me,

```
mv -f /var/lib/docker/* /data/tmp
systemctl restart docker.service
docker system prune -a
```

Answer (score 4):

this could be caused when disk usage got full you can check this by doing `df -h` if so clean up unwanted space or can prune docker by doing `docker system prune` once after freeing up space , stop docker because thin_check cannot be run on live metadata.

```
systemctl stop docker 
thin_check /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
```

check for error if noting clear check flag by

```
thin_check --clear-needs-check-flag /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
```

then start docker

```
systemctl start docker.service
```

if thin check not installed

```
yum install -y device-mapper-persistent-data
```

for centos

```
apt-get install -y thin-provisioning-tools
```

Answer (score 2):

Got this today.

```
sudo reboot
```

Problem's out.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter another dm_task_run issue during `docker import`, for my case, I `yum erase docker.x86_64; yum install docker.x86_64; systemctl start docker.service` works.