# Docker dm_task_run failed error when creating image

Tags: docker

I'm attempting to create a Docker image with a MarkLogic RPM file installed (based on CentOS7). I successfully created some images like this earlier, but now it fails every time. I got this error:

```
Step 5/7 : COPY MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-5.2.x86_64.rpm /tmp/MarkLogic.rpm
failed to create rwlayer: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreateSnapDeviceRaw) dm_task_run failed
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30719896/docker-dm-task-run-failed-error) and the MarkLogic RPM is fairly large (139MB), so I purged all unneeded images. Since I work in a Linux VM, I increased the drive space to 50GB, so now I have 35GB free. But trying it again, I still get the same error. Even though the MarkLogic RPM is pretty hefty, I should have plenty of space to create the image now.

Anyone know the real source of the error and how to overcome it?

Using **Docker 18.09.0** and **CentOS 7.6**.

Comment: Consider using the `overlay2` storage driver rather than the `devicemapper` driver. This will generally be both more performant and more manageable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked directly with MarkLogic on this issue. While they do officially support Docker *now*, it is only officially supported for versions **9.0-5** and above. Since i was using version 8.0-5.x, it's not surprising it didn't work. Following the instructions [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/installation/procedures#id_pgfId-1141475), I was able to successfully create a MarkLogic Docker image, run it as a container and connect to it.